# post body class for current user only if they are the post author

Tags: custom-post-types, author, body-class

I'm trying to find a way to add a body class "author" IF the current user is the author of the post they are viewing.

This is what I have so far...

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

    if ( !$current_user->ID == $post->post_author ) {

        $classes[] = 'post-author';

    }

    return $classes;

}
```

Comment: You have wrong `if` expression. [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't working because you haven't defined or retrieved the `$current_user` or `$post` variables from anyway. You've also got a `!` here for some reason: `!$current_user->ID`, which will just break the condition.

You need to use the appropriate functions to get their values, and also use `is_single()` to make sure you're viewing a single post (otherwise the post author could be missing or something unexpected).

```
add_filter(
    'body_class',
    function( $classes ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            $post = get_queried_object();
            $user = wp_get_current_user();

            if ( $user->ID == $post->post_author ) {
                $classes[] = 'post-author';
            }
        }

        return $classes;
    }
);
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the !. Thanks for the showing me how to retrieve the user and post :)

Comment: Fixed the answer, last `}` should've been `);`